# stri_replace messing up characters

Tags: php, email, character-encoding

I am getting a page via curl with this code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$message = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

I now want to make some replacements to the code in $message, but before that I dump the code in a file:

```
file_put_contents('debug_before_replace.txt',$message);
```

When I take a look at this file, all the text seems fine, for example I have here the title:

```
<title>D.O.C.| Jantar Vínico Quinta do Portal | Quinta-feira, 25 de Junho 2009</title>
```

Now I do the replace:

$message = str_ireplace(   array(
                            'body>',
                            '/body>'
                            ),
                        array(
                            $fraseemcima,
                            $frasebaixo
                            ),
                        $message
                );

And now I dump the $message to another file:

```
file_put_contents('debug_after_replace.txt',$message);
```

When I take a look at the file I see this:

```
<title>D.O.C.| Jantar VÃ­nico Quinta do Portal | Quinta-feira, 25 de Junho 2009</title>
```

And I have all sorts of messed up chars in the rest of the code.

Anyone understand why stri_replace is messing this up? I am trying to send some mail and this messes up everything.

NOTE: In the replace I do have the body and /body tags correct, but if I added the < SO would remove the words

EDIT: I have fixed it!!

Whit this simple line everything works and looks great in outlook:

```
$message = utf8_decode(curl_exec($ch));
```

Thanks to macbirdie and S. Gehrig for pointing me in the right direction.
Guess I still have some learning to do when it comes to charsets

Thanks again

Comment: What's the charset of the the html document you retrieve via curl?

Answer (score 1):

The text you're editing is most likely UTF-8 or some other multi-byte encoding encoded. `str_ireplace()` is **not** multi-byte safe and operates on single bytes. This leads to a situation where your multi-byte characters might be destroyed.
You should also check, if the document contains a **B**yte-**O**rder-**M**ark (**BOM**) - this could also lead to some problems (according to [this comment](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php#72344))

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use a multi-byte-aware function for character replacement, like [`mb_eregi_replace()`](http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-eregi-replace.php) instead.

If there is any, the file can also lose the [byte-order mark](http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-eregi-replace.php) that unicode uses to indicate what endiannes the UTF-8 extended characters are written in as it may be lost because the replacement function may treat it as non-text, but that's purely speculation.

Comment: Yes this might be the problem. Too bad there is no mb_str_replace.

I'll test this and report here.

Thanks again